# What happened if provisioning profiles are deleted of live app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am just want to know if my provisioning profiles from developer account deleted then app will work or not.

Comment: Your app will be work.

Comment: It doesn't affect the live application but you will have to create the new profile if you require to provide the update of the application.

Comment: It should be specified which provisioning profile you are asking about ( developer, adhoc , app Store, entreprise developer, entreprise adhoc, entreprise in-house)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry. Even if provisioning profiles are deleted , your live app will work.

However you will not be able to run the app in XCode using the old (deleted) provisioning profile, as It will show a code signing error I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jlthin.